# How to work Ajax libs jquery and jQuery CDN in single page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I called Ajax jquery for supersized slider in the head and called jquery-1.11.0. min. j's for mixitup plugin. One is work that is called last. how can work two plugin?

> ```
> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> //call it
> ```
>
> for supersized slider
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> ```
>
> //call it for mixitup plugin

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the second one, it will overwrite the first one and you'll want the newer version. 
Mixitup should work with 1.11.0 as well, so you don't need 1.6.1.

See here, Mixitup also recommends newest version.
https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/learn/tutorial/get-started/

Answer (score 0):

you should not include Jquery Script twice in a single page for multiple plugins which are dependent on Jquery Script because including it once is enough for every plugin dependent on it to work, unless the plugin rely on a specific version of Jquery..

**NOTE** - the jquery Script should be included before any other script is included that depends on it..

if you want to include multiple version of Jquery than you can use [Jquery's noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).